# What is the current status of Gaudiya Math?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

(1) Are they unified or are there schisms in the organization?

(2) Do they regard ISKCON as part of their math?

Note to the duplicate police; not the same as

[Are there any philosophical differences between Gaudiya Math and ISKCON?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21538/are-there-any-philosophical-differences-between-gaudiya-math-and-iskcon)

This is a purely organizational question.

Comment: How is the politics of whether one organisation considers another legitimate without any philosophical points as material reference a question on Hinduism? Voting to close.

Comment: I guess in your sect/sub-sect organization is the same as politics.  How a sect is organized is a legitimate question.

Comment: No - this question is asking for legitimacy derived not from philosophy/theology but other reasons that is beyond the scope of the site.

Comment: the word "legitimacy" or anything remotely related to it does not occur in the question.

Comment: This question explicitly states it is not interested in philosophical differences, it wouldn't be going out on a limb in saying that theology is also not what is being asked for. The question is asking for "purely organisational" aspect of schisms and whether ISKCON is considered a part of the math. Given above details, it would be well within sanity to conclude this is a question of legitimacy and that too of one related assuredly to that of polity.

Comment: No, they don't regard ISKCON as a part of their Math.

Comment: @sk this seems more of a political question/opinion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are they unified or are there schisms in the organization?

Well, they are unified as of now. The last time there was a rift in the Gaudiya Math was during the late 1980s. The rift ended once Srila Bhakti Pramode Puri Goswami Maharaj broke away resulting in the formation of the Sree Gopinatha Gaudiya Math in 1989.

> Do they regard ISKCON as a part of their math?

No, definitely not. They are absolutely different and separate organisations. ISKCON is one of the many break away factions of the Gaudiya Math. I don't have any sources to quote acharyas of Gaudiya Math saying they don't consider ISKCON as a part of their organisation but I can quote some old letters of Prabhupada where he slams the Gaudiya Mission:

> **Srila Prabhupada’s Letter to Yamuna 11/18/70:**
>
> **“Regarding the Gaudiya Math, our position has nothing to do with them. They cannot do anything and if somebody does something, they will be envious.** That is the nature of third class men.”
>
> ---
>
> **Srila Prabhupada’s Letter to Sukadeva 11/14/73:**
>
> **“Regarding the Gaudiya Math books being circulated there, who is distributing? Who is sending these books? The Gaudiya Math does not sell our books, why we should sell their books. Who has introduced these books? Let me know. These books should not at all be circulated in our Society. Bhakti Vilas Tirtha is very much antagonistic to our society and he has no clear conception of devotional service. He is contaminated.** Anyway, who has introduced these books? You say that you would read only one book if that was all that I had written, so you teach others to do like that. You have very good determination.”
>
> ---
>
> **Srila Prabhupada’s Letter to Gurukrpa, 9/30/75:**
>
> “Why is there this politics? This is not good. If politics come, then the preaching will be stopped. That is the difficulty. As soon as politics come, everything is spoiled. **In the Gaudiya Math the politics is still going on. My Guru Maharaja left in 1936, and now it is 1976, so after 40 years the litigation is still going on.** Do not come to this.”
>
> ---

So ISKCON has no affiliation with Gaudiya Math.